# how to use vlookup in excel 2010 to search 2 variables

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, vlookup

elp

I have below colum

```
A       B     C         
CBL     20  21000   
CBL     40  26580   
CBL    40HC 25780   
CIPL    20  18000   
CIPL    40  20000   
CIPT    20  21700   
CIPT    40  26580
```

when i do a vlookup, to search for CBL in another tab, I want it to also search column b, so it will shows the correct results from column C.

CanI use vlookup or other formulae?

pls

Answer (score 0):

If Column C is numeric, you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=Var1_)*(B1:B10=Var2_)*C1:C10)
```

where Var1_ and Var2_ are your two variables.

Here is a screen shot of what I think you want.  If you want something else, you will need to clarify.

[image]

Comment: It works here using Excel 2007 and your data, returning the contents of corresponding row of Col C where the same row in Col A contains Var1, and the same row in Col B contains Var2.  If that is not what you want, then you will have to be more specific.  I will add a screen shot to my response.